# How to load different html files in QUnit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I'm using QUnit for unit testing js and jquery.
My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>QUnit Test Suite</title>

 <script src="../lib/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.16.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.16.0.js"></script>

  <!--This is where I may have to add startPage.html--->
  <script src="../login.js"></script>

  <script src="../test/myTests.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, I'm adding login.js as shown and I'm getting references correctly to objects defined in login.js.

However, functions in login.js contains references to some dom elements defined in startPage.html which is located elsewhere.

So, if I say `$('#login-btn')`, it is throwing an error. Is there any way to fix this?

Can I 
(a) refer to startPage.html to my qunit page given above?
(b) refer to or load startPage.html in the file where I'm running tests (myTests.js):

```
QUnit.test( "a test", function( assert ) {
    assert.equal( 1, "1", "String '1' and number 1 have the same value" );//works
    assert.equal( login.abc, "abc", "Abc" );//works with attributes
    assert.equal(($("#userid").val()),'',  'Userid field is present');//fails
    assert.equal( login.ValidUserId(), true, "ValidUserId" );//fails with functions
});
```

Does QUnit provide any method to load Html/php files so they'll be defined prior to testing. Like 'fixtures' in jasmine?

**EDIT:** Please also tell what to do in case I have startPage.php

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. The simplest is just to use the built-in [QUnit "fixtures" element](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#keeping-tests-atomic). In your QUnit HTML file, simply add any HTML you want in the div with the id of `qunit-fixture`. Any HTML you put in there will be reset to what it was on load before each test (automatically).

```
<html>
  ...
  <body>
    <div id='qunit'></div>
    <div id='qunit-fixture'>
      <!-- everything in here is reset before each test -->
      <form>
        <input id='userid' type='text'>
        <input id='login-btn' type='submit'>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the HTML in the fixture doesn't really have to match what you have in production, but obviously you can do that. Really, you should just be adding the minimal necessary HTML so that you can minimize any side effects on your tests.

The second option is to actually pull in the HTML from that login page and [delay the start of the QUnit tests](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.config/) until the HTML loading is complete:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.16.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    // tell QUnit you're not ready to start right away...
    QUnit.config.autostart = false;

    $.ajax({
      url: '/path/to/startPage.html',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(html) {
        // find specific elements you want...
        var elem = $(html).find(...);
        $('#qunit-fixture').append(elem);

        QUnit.start();  // ...tell QUnit you're ready to go
      }
    });
    </script>

    ...
  </head>

  ...
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll check it out.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to make it work with php files instead of html? Suppose I have startPage.php, then what? I'm getting an error.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not going to work with the dynamic include th3e way I've coded it. The problem is that you aren't going to be executing the PHP code, so there would be no HTML output to parse through. I think you're best bet is going to using `<div id="qunit-fixture">`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this without using jquery is as follows

```
QUnit.config.autostart = false;

window.onload = function() {
    var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onloadend = function () {
            if(xhr.status == 200) {
                var txt = xhr.responseText;
                var start = txt.indexOf('<body>')+6;
                var end = txt.indexOf('</body>');;
                var body_text = txt.substring(start, end);
                var qunit_fixture_body = document.getElementById('qunit-fixture');
                qunit_fixture_body.innerHTML = body_text;
            }
            QUnit.start();
        }

        xhr.open("GET", "index.html");
        xhr.send();
    } else {
        QUnit.start(); //If getting the html file from server fails run tests and fail anyway
    }
}
```